# how to open windows one after another on hitting ok button in perl tk?

Tags: perl, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I am implementing a gui using perl/tk.

I wish to hit OK button after filling values in entrybox on my first window. Now after hitting OK button another window will popup with some new entry fields. In the same way, if again hitting OK button it should open another new window till the finish button comes.
And there should be a previous button too to go to the previous window.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: You're making some kind of wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tk::NoteBook](http://search.cpan.org/~ni-s/Tk/pod/NoteBook.pod) can be helpful here.  It shows a progression through the windows with the tabs so the user can tell how far they are.  Pages can be set to 'disabled' so the user can't switch to them without using your [Prev][Next] buttons (making sure that your code gets run on each page flip).

A quick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::NoteBook;

my $mw=MainWindow->new();
my $nb=$mw->NoteBook->pack(-expand=>1,-fill=>'both');
my $page1=$nb->add('page1',-label=>'Start');
my $page2=$nb->add('page2',-label=>'Finish',-state=>'disabled');
$page1->Button(-text=>'Next',-command=>\&next_page)->pack;
$page2->Button(-text=>'Exit',-command=>sub{exit;})->pack;
MainLoop;

sub next_page() {
 $nb->pageconfigure('page2',-state=>'normal');
 $nb->raise('page2');
 $nb->pageconfigure('page1',-state=>'disabled');
}
```

Comment: How can I set a entry field value to be empty on hitting clear button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to create windows with Tk and you are not expecting someone here to code it for you with that question.

That being said, you should create a class to do this with an instance of that class. The instance can hold any properties (or several values in a single property) and your Tk application can work with that instance to assign any new values and be able to read them back if you need to go back/forward in your process.

As for the Tk application, you can create a sub that uses your class instance and a step number as arguments, or you can create another class to control the right step in another property and trigger the right method according to the current step or any signal of "next" or "previous" buttons.

See [this Tk tutorial](http://www.bin-co.com/perl/perl_tk_tutorial/contents.php), is very good. You can Google for more Tk examples.

See [this Perl OOP tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_oo_perl.htm) to lean the basics about creating classes and object oriented programming in Perl. Again, you can Google for more on the subject.

Also, if you're feeling like learning a lot more and creating really nice and much more modern GUIs in Perl, I would highly recommend looking into [Alien::wxWidgets](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Alien-wxWidgets/lib/Alien/wxWidgets.pm), which is a CPAN library for the [wxWidgets Project](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/book/index.htm).

HTH

Francisco

Comment: May you please provide me some links or examples that can help me implementing the above gui?

Comment: I just added more info and links to the answer. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 0):

user1468315 asked:

> How can I set a entry field value to be empty on hitting clear button?

I believe something like this should do it.

```
$entry = $mw->Entry()->pack;

$button = $mw->Button(
-command => sub{$entry->delete(0, 'end');}
)->pack;
```